# How to convert Matlab's Tiff function in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, tiff

I'm trying to convert a function I use in MATLAB to merge an RGB image with an IR image (both in JPG formats) to create a Tiff image with 4 bands (R, G, B, IR). However, I have some problem implementing the `Tiff` function, as it looks like that `Tiff` is not implemented in Octave.

Someone know how can I convert the `Tiff`  part of following function to Octave?

```
for fidx = 1:numel(filelist1)
   rgb = imread(fullfile(folder1, filelist1{fidx}));
   numrows = size(rgb,1);
   numcols = size(rgb,2);
   ir = imread(fullfile(folder2, filelist2{fidx}));
   data = cat(3,rgb,ir);


   t = Tiff(fullfile(folderout, sprintf(outfilepattern, fidx))','w');

setTag(t,'Photometric',Tiff.Photometric.RGB);
setTag(t,'Compression',Tiff.Compression.None);
setTag(t,'BitsPerSample',8);
setTag(t,'SamplesPerPixel',4);
setTag(t,'SampleFormat',Tiff.SampleFormat.UInt);
setTag(t,'ExtraSamples',Tiff.ExtraSamples.Unspecified);
setTag(t,'ImageLength',numrows);
setTag(t,'ImageWidth',numcols);
setTag(t,'TileLength',32);
setTag(t,'TileWidth',32);
setTag(t,'PlanarConfiguration',Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky);

   write(t,data);
   close(t);
```

Comment: If `Tiff` is not implemented in Octave directly, you'll have to translate it yourself. Translating code, however, is too broad for Stack Overflow. Type `edit Tiff` in MATLAB's command window to get the source code, see what you can translate from that.

Comment: `Tiff` is an open format so you can found the tiff structure online (which byte correspond to what). Also Tiff is not a compression type it's a container. So you will have to deal with several compression type (specified in the tiff header).